# Graph Coloring in Propositional Logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, coloring

Let G be a legally colored graph with k colors; this means that each two adjacent vertices have different colors, and the total number of colors in G is k.

In addition, the edges of the graph are colored so that the color of the edge is similar to one of the color of the two vertices it connects.

I am supposed to concoct a formula in propositional logic for coloring *the edges* of the graph, given the formula for coloring the vertices, however I am confused in doing the proper formulas for the edges. So the questions are:

(1) Which atomic statements should be added to those I already defined?

(2) Which statements should I add to depict the edge coloring of the graph?
I thought of this:

T= {$(P_u^i,P_w^j )^S | s⋲ [i,j],  u,w⋲V,(u,w)⋲E $}

Vertices coloring -

[image]

The number in the bottom is the number of the vertices, and the "i" depicts the color of the vertices

[image]

This means that the vertices at least have one color

[image]

This means that each vertices has only one color

[image]

This means that connected vertices have different colors

Comment: What is a *similar* coloring?

Comment: It means that  it has the same color.